# 2D Terrain Generation

Tags: 2d, terrain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a random “world” in a tile engine?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18735/how-can-i-create-a-random-world-in-a-tile-engine)

I need some advice as to how I should go about coding a 2D Terrain Generator for a game written in C.  I need to create a terrain generator similar to the game minecraft, but in a 2D landscape.

Comment: Bird's eye or platformer?

Comment: This is way too broad a question. There are many kinds of 2D games, each with their own kind of game. What _exactly_ are you trying to make?

Comment: Other than the specified language (which shouldn't really make a difference since the answer is going to be an algorithm and not actual code), this doesn't seem to be any different than this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/terrain-generation-for-tile-based-2d-platformer

Comment: or this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18735/how-can-i-create-a-random-world-in-a-tile-engine, or this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14238/what-is-a-good-technique-for-2d-tile-based-terrain-generation-meeting-these-requ